# Meteor handlebar nested condition error

Tags: meteor

```
{{#each array}}
   {{#if conditoin}}
        ...   
   {{else}}
     {{#if condition}}
            ....
     {{/if}}
            ...
     {{#if condition}}
            ...
     {{/if}}
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

so this is my nested condition but in the first closing if under else an error is thrown:

```
 Unexpected closing template tag {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks correct to me, but it could be that you simply don't have balanced tags (e.g., `div`) inside your conditional blocks. Keep in mind that Meteor uses strict xhtml parsing. So things that are OK to a browser, such as

```
<ul>
  <li>one
  <li>two
</ul>
```

are not OK to Meteor (missing `</li>` tags).

Comment: OMG thank you found the problem now, I was open a div in one if and close that div in another if.